# Colored image to matrix and matrix back to an image

Tags: java

I have a color image of MxN, in row x column format. I want to store all the red components of the image in a separate matrix, all the green component in a separate matrix and all the blue component in a separate matrix. Perform transformation on all the three matrix and generate back the shuffled RGB image. I am able to store it in single matrix using the below code, but unable to store it in three separate matrices.

`double[][] img = new double[bi.getHeight()][bi.getWidth()];`

`img[i][j] = bi.getRGB(i, j);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Understanding BufferedImage.getRGB output values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761438/understanding-bufferedimage-getrgb-output-values), you have several possibilities:

You need to initialize the arrays:

```
int[][] blue = new int[bi.getHeight()][bi.getWidth()];
int[][] green = new int[bi.getHeight()][bi.getWidth()]; 
int[][] red = new int[bi.getHeight()][bi.getWidth()]; 
int[][] alpha = new int[bi.getHeight()][bi.getWidth()];
```

1) simplest to understand, bit more overhead: use [`Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

```
Color mycolor = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
red[x][y] = mycolor.getRed();
blue[x][y] = mycolor.getBlue();
green[x][y] = mycolor.getGreen();
```

2) [do those computations by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761560/1587329)

```
int color = bi.getRGB(x, y);

// Components will be in the range of 0..255:
blue[x][y] = color & 0xff;
green[x][y] = (color & 0xff00) >> 8;
red[x][y] = (color & 0xff0000) >> 16;
alpha[x][y] = (color & 0xff000000) >>> 24;
```

3) [print as a String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761702/1587329) and extract the values again (this is more of theoretical value, do not use this without knowing what you do)

print the value as an unsigned 32bit hex value:

```
String s = Integer.toString(bi.getRGB(x,y), 16)
blue[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(24, 32), 2);
green[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(16, 24), 2);
red[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 16), 2);
alpha[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 8), 2);
```

Each two characters of the output will be one part of the ARGB set.

4) use [`ColorModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html) (it is unclear whether it can be done)

It has `getAlpha`, `getRed`, etc methods, but the pixels are a single 1-D array. If someone knows how to use it, feel free.