# How to decode an int into RGBA?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

New to bit manipulation here. BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y) returns an int containing all the RGBA values. How does one decode the bits in the int to get four 0 - 255 values for RGBA?
Thanks :)

Comment: From [here](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5901.0): `buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
            buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding BufferedImage.getRGB output values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761438/understanding-bufferedimage-getrgb-output-values)

Comment: A quick search on stackoverflow gives me below, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801366/convert-rgb-values-to-integer

Comment: maybe `ColorModel.getRGBDefault().getAlpha(rgb)`. `...getBlue(rgb)`, `...getGreen(rgb)` and `...getRed(rgb)`