# What will be the value of int a = bufferedImageSource.getRGB(x,y)?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am a bit confused exactly what value will be stored in the variable a. Please can someone explain me with an example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,int)) is not clear?

Comment: Did you see this stackoverflow answer? [Understanding Buffered Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761438/understanding-bufferedimage-getrgb-output-values)

Comment: As per the doccumentation `Returns: an integer pixel in the default RGB color model and default sRGB colorspace.` Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int- Try it and you will see what the result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BufferedImage.getRGB() docs says:

> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this default model does not match the image ColorModel. There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method.

To divide this int to a R,G,B values you can use bitwise operations:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(10, 10, 10);
int a = bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0);

int red = (a >> 16) & 255;
int green = (a >> 8) & 255;
int blue = (a) & 255;
System.out.println(a + " r:" + red + ", g:" + green + ", b:" + blue);
```